# Resources for working on an app in Xamarin using C# for UI rather than xml?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am writing an app in xamarin.forms using C# for my UI. However, I am having trouble finding any resources to help me with certain things (like databinding for instance) that are strictly using c# as opposed to both c# and xml. If anyone can point me in the direction of where i could find those resources (if they exist) that would be awesome. (P.S. yes I have googled every single way I can possibly think of but all the keywords you'd use such as xamarin + c# + UI etc always just keep returning more results using xml)

Comment: This is too broad of a question for SO, and is also asking for links to resources, which is off-topic.  It would be better if you gave us a specific example of what you're having trouble with so we can help you solve that specific problem.

Comment: You want examples of building the UI with only c# code and not XAML ? This is in the microsoft docs

Comment: @Jason Sorry, wasn't really sure where else to ask. Specifically, I would like to understand data-binding when using strictly c#, however, I am sure I will come across many more topics I need answers on and thats why I thought I'd ask for broader resources so I don't have to come back here everytime. Literally every search i do just keeps returning examples with xml

Comment: @Greggz if its in microsoft docs then I have no been able to find it because everything I've seen there regarding xamarin.forms is using xml in combination with c#

Comment: @paul As Jason provided, the link provide the way to use c# set the bindind. If you wanna more details for this, you could download the source file from the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/databindingdemos/  The `CodeBindingPage` performs the way to set the binding in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

the Xamarin [binding docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings) have samples in C# and XAML

```
// set the binding context for the page
this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();

// create a label 
Label myLabel = new Label();

// set the binding to a property on the VM
myLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Description");
```

Comment: Thanks but where is the documentation for this? The link you posted is for examples using c# and xml, my issue is I want the documentation for how to do it ONLY with c# in the way you demonstrated